# Getting rank of row

Tags: mysql, window-functions, rank

I am using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64)`.

I am having a table referral:

```
CREATE TABLE `referrals` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referred_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `referrals_email_unique` (`email`)
);
```

In the table you basically insert the person and who referred it.

I have created the following leaderboard:

```
select
        referred_by,
        count(referred_by) as referred_by_count,
            @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
from
        referrals r,
    (
    SELECT
        @curRank := 0) o
group by
        referred_by
order by
        referred_by_count DESC;
```

This gives me:

| referred_by | referred_by_count | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 | 5 |
| 11 | 2 | 6 |
| 15 | 1 | 8 |
| 12 | 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 9 | 1 | 7 |

However, I would like to get:

| referred_by | referred_by_count | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 13 | 2 | 4 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 |
| 15 | 1 | 6 |
| 12 | 1 | 7 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | 1 | 9 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o42zo6XiJZzEbrrVDfgQR4/3)

I created the following [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o42zo6XiJZzEbrrVDfgQR4/3) using the faker php plugin.

I tried using the mysql `RANK()` function. However, I am struggeling how to correctly use it.

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
select referred_by, referred_by_count, @rank := @rank+1
from (
    select  referred_by,
            count(referred_by) as referred_by_count
    from referrals r
    group by referred_by
    order by referred_by_count DESC, referred_by
) as t
cross join ( select @Rank := 0 ) o
order by referred_by_count desc, referred_by;
```

But I don't think that the result is guaranteed to be deterministic. RANK() is BTW a window function present in MySQL 8+. If possible upgrade to a newer version of MySQL, abusing variables like above may introduce mysterious bugs in your application

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o42zo6XiJZzEbrrVDfgQR4/3)

Comment: Is there any advantages of using `cross join (select ...)` for UDV initialization instead of `where (@rank := 0) = 0`?

Comment: Not that I can think of. I just translated the "," join used in the query

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need `ROW_NUMBER()`, supported in MySQL 8+

```
select
        referred_by,
        count(referred_by) as referred_by_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(referred_by) DESC) AS rnk
from
        referrals r
group by
        referred_by
order by
        referred_by_count DESC;
```

[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o42zo6XiJZzEbrrVDfgQR4/3)

Note that the results are non-deterministic for tied rows: you may want ot add another column to order by.